# OWL Api class assertion

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I have two classes `A` and `B` and I want to assert that `A` is `relatedClass` `B`.

I want to do it at a class level, at first I thought of creating an object property `relatedClass` and adding that assertion. But I can only do that between individuals.

```
OWLObjectProperty related = dataFactory.getOWLObjectProperty(IOR + "#relatedClass");
OWLAxiom axiom = dataFactory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(related, classA, classB);
```

This is incorrect because the method expects `classA` and `classB` to be individuals.

Is it possible to set relationships between classes? How is it done using the OWL API?

I'm following [this pattern](http://ontologydesignpatterns.org/wiki/Submissions:Pattern_for_re-engineering_a_term-based_thesaurus%2C_which_follows_the_recordbased_data_model%2C_into_an_ontology_schema) to transform a taxonomy and it says:

> Assert that competence is relatedClass of performance

Where both `competence` and `performance` are classes.

---

### Update

Ok, so based on your answers and comments I've been trying to understand which relationship is the pattern talking about. But I'm at a loss.

Firstly, the meaning of related is the same that the meaning of `skos:related` so it's very general:

> The property skos:related is used to assert an associative link between two SKOS concepts.

It's is used when two concepts are related but one isn't a more general or specific concept of the other. Plus, it's a symmetric property. One example from my domain is that "Information Systems" is related to "Systems security" (but as you can see it's a very generic kind of relationship).

Here is the diagram that is included as part of the pattern:

[image]

And here is a (very blurry, but that's how it looks on the paper) version of the diagram for the example:

[image]

So what I'm getting from here is that it needs to be an `ObjectProperty` and I have to set up the domain and range, but how does it work if:

```
ClassA related ClassB
ClassC related ClassD
```

How do I set the domain and range in that case? Or do you think I should have one per pair of related classes?

Comment: Define "related" ... OWL supports subclass, equivalence, and disjointness relationship between classes.

Comment: Relationships between classes are either descriptions of extension overlap (inclusion, disjunction, equivalence, or more complex class expressions), or annotation properties. Your `related` relation might be an annotation property. Annotation property assertions are created with similar methods to object property assertions.

Comment: @AKSW I have updated the question with a better definition of "related"

Comment: @Ignazio thanks, that's what I read on another similar question. I have updated with some more information about the pattern intents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be achieved using the OWL API because OWL does not support it. In specific the [OWL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#def_object_property) states

> Object properties connect pairs of individuals.

Hence, object properties do not link classes of individuals but individuals. The best you can do is to say that if 2 individuals are linked via an object property, those individuals belong to specific classes, which can be achieved using domain and range restrictions. I.e.:

```
ObjectProperty: relatedClass
  Domain: A
  Range: B
```

Using the OWL API you will need to do something as follows:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLDataFactory dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory(); 

IRI relatedClassPropertyIRI = IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#relatedClass");
IRI aClassIRI = IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#A");
IRI bClassIRI = IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#B");

OWLObjectProperty relatedClassProperty = dataFactory.getOWLObjectProperty(relatedClassPropertyIRI);

OWLClass aClass = dataFactory.getOWLClass(aClassIRI);
OWLClass bClass = dataFactory.getOWLClass(bClassIRI);

dataFactory.getOWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom(relatedClassProperty, aClass);
dataFactory.getOWLObjectPropertyRangeAxiom(relatedClassProperty, bClass);
```

If you now use a property assertion axiom like

```
OWLAxiom axiom = dataFactory.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(related, individualA, individualB);
```

the reasoner will infer that `individualA` belongs to class `A` and `individualB` to class `B`.

**Update**

To deal with multiple related classes you have to use the unions of the classes for the domain and range:

```
ObjectProperty: relatedClass
 Domain: A or C
 Range: B or D
```

Comment: Great, so the idea of setting up the domains makes sense with what the pattern states, but how does it work if I want to use the same property for more relationships? I explained this better on the updated version of the question